# Google Chrome rendering floated text on multiple lines

Tags: css, google-chrome

I recently updated Google Chrome to V38, and I've noticed that text sitting inside a floating div element renders itself on two lines. This is occurring even though there is plenty of room for the text and absolutely nothing forcing it onto a second line.

Here are some screenshot's of this issue

Firefox:
[image: FF Screenshot]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

The only solution I've found is to add `white-space: nowrap` onto every single affected item, but that's far from efficient seeing as how many items are/could be affected.

Comment: Does it actually have enough room or are you saying that just because FireFox works and Chrome doesn't?  I know off-hand that a recent Google Chrome version updated the dredded anti-aliasing bug that has been plaguing text in chrome for a few years.  I would wager that change has added a pixel or so to the overall width of your font, thus causing it to collapse.  This is of course assuming that the above button has a fixed width, which I can't say for sure is the case as you didn't provide us any code samples.

Comment: Well, after investigating a bit, I have found that it is related to that anti-aliasing bug you mentioned. I added `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` to my css a long while ago in a vain attempt to correct that bug, but that appears to be what's causing the problem here. To think something so innocuous is causing me so much grief.

Comment: Glad I can put you in the right direction.

Comment: removing text-rendering: optimizeLegibility did it for me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is fixed by remove css code: `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility`